# WooCommerce REST API GET multiple products by ID

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I need to display all related products by eah product I have in my list.

Eg, In my app I have 3 products with id 1, 2, 3
product id 1 has 5,6,7 as related, product id 2 with related 8 and 9 etc..

Now I have an array with all the related `[5,6,7,8,9..]`
How can I get only this ones from REST API?

I can call by single ID like that `site.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/5/`

But doesn't work with multiple IDs like `../products/5/6/` or `../products/5,6/`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you could use parameter 'include' to achieve that like below :

```
site.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/?include=5,6,7,8,9
```

This will limit results to specific Id's.

Answer (score 0):

On version 3 of Woocommerce it should be

```
https://test.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumer_key=ck_&consumer_secret=cs_&include=1,2,3
```