# How to get related products in WooCommerce REST API(related_ids)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?related_ids=6032

here, above API is displaying all the products,
But I need to get only related products by **related_ids** Attribute, So What's the issue with this API? I have checked others like **slug** Attribute, works fine.

seems like related_ids not functioning. but I have done it according to the DOC.
**https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#products**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without your code, the community cannot help you. See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Check this one out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52533166/woocommerce-rest-api-get-multiple-products-by-id

Answer (score 1):

wp-json/wc/v2/products?include=5,6,7,8,9

This will get only products with mentioned ids.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).